# what is the source of the following issue in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an existing src/ java directory with all the structure.

I created a new java project in Eclipse, and the src directory is read well into the project naturally.

However, there are a few issues:

- (a) I can't run anything (the Java interpreter can't find the class, even though it is part of the source),
- (b) errors do not mark the file as having an error, they are only marked at the relevant line in the source code (never had that issue before)
- (c) there is a large exclamation mark next to the title of the java project in the explorer on the left handside.

I am probably misconfiguring something, but I am not sure what. Is there a way to at least see what's the cause of the large exclamation mark? I am pretty sure it will give some info.

Comment: What do you see in the Problems window?

Comment: First thing I would look into is the build path. It's probably lost the connection to the JRE, for some reason. Eclipse does that, at times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your source directory is not part of the eclipse project. right click on the project (in the eclipse explorer), get the properties open and click on java build path. Check that your source directory is listed in the source tab.

Comment: my source directory is listed there... unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: If you click on the 'Problems' window (usually in the lower part of eclipse) it should tell you what the build problems are. I'm assuming your project is using a JRE that is configured properly - if that's not the case then that should also show in the Problems window. You should also try and clean your project (Project --> clean)

Answer (score 0):

The JRE reference on that project is probably misconfigured. Theck the **Project > Properties > Java Build Path** and see if you have the JRE library referenced correctly. If not, Add it through **Add Library > JRE System Library**

Answer (score 0):

Your java project is having build issues and hence the files are not getting compiled. **Primarily its due to build path.**  Correct the build path by going `Project-> Properties -> Java Build Path` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with your path set up 
kindly follow

```
1 : Project-> (right click)BUildPath -> Libraries
```

check if there is any red sign on any library , just remove and add it again with the correct path .

```
2 : if you are using some jar file , add as external jar from the same process .
```

3 : if this doesnt serves the purpose ,

```
open window -> showview -> markers
```

read the errors here and try the quick fix available .if the prob stays , let us know